# how to remove this required message "Complete this field." .slds-has-error .slds-form-element__help

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

```
<html lang="en-GB" dir="ltr"><head><title>Register</title><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/b2bcustomers/favicon.ico?v=2"><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, minimum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">

<div lightning-input_input="" class="slds-form-element__help" id="help-message-177" data-help-message="" role="alert">Complete this field. </div>

</html>
```

Comment: Is this the markup that you use in your LWC (according to the tag)? Or where is this taken from? If this is taken from the html file of your LWC, there appear to be to be several misunderstandings on how to code LWC. You might want to have a look at the introduction [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/build-lightning-web-components).

Comment: @FelixvanHove I have taken from LWC when the required field is not entered then above div tag line is enabled . I need to remove this error line "Complete this field." and to display empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification) lists a lot of attributes used to set specific error message. The one you're looking for is `message-when-value-missing`

> **Error message to be displayed when the value is missing**. The valueMissing error can be returned when you specify the required attribute for any input type.

You could just provide an empty string as value. Trying the following code you'll see just the red border and no errore message:

```html
<lightning-input
    type="text"
    label="No error message"
    required
    message-when-value-missing=" ">
</lightning-input>
```